# in mule 4 transformer Is it possible to use above defined key below

Tags: anypoint-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I am working on mule 4. I want to use the key defined above in transformer below. for example, my transformer is

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    name : usama,
    age : 24,
    value: age
}
```

here in the third key i.e. "data" I want to use the value of "age" key.

Can anyone help?

the output should be as defined below

```
{
    name : usama,
    age : 24,
    value: 24
}
```

Comment: the top is not valid dataweave as 'usama' and 'age' aren't defined as variables or functions. If they're strings, please add quotes around them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you can either define a global variable and reference it in both places or use a [do block](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-flow-control#control_flow_do)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var age = 24
---
{
    name : "usama",
    age : age,
    value: age
}
```

Comment: Do block example:
do {
  var age = 24
  ---
  {
    name: "usama",
    age: age,
    value: age
  }
}

Comment: Thanks. it is working. I just want to confirm that defining a global variable is the only way.